# codeigniter insert oracle error Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php Line Number: 330

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, insert

So i get this error when i try to insert in an oracle database. I think i have everything configured correctly, and im doing things right, but dont know where the problem is, cause i get no number error.

ERROR:

```
Error Number:
INSERT INTO "articulo" ("id", "titulo", "descripcion", "cuerpo") VALUES (1, 'titulo', 'descripcion', 'CUERPO')
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

Controller Class:

```
class Articulos extends CI_Controller {
function index(){
    //cargo el helper de url, con funciones para trabajo con URL del sitio
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->database();  
    //cargo el modelo de artículos
    $this->load->model('Articulo_model');

    //pido los ultimos artículos al modelo
    $this->Articulo_model->introducir_articulos();
}}
```

The function in the model class:

```
function introducir_articulos(){
    $data = array(
            'id'=>1,
           'descripcion'=>"descripcion",
           'cuerpo'=>"CUERPO",
           'titulo'=>"titulo"
        );

    $this->db->insert('articulo', $data);
```

}

since this has just to insert, it has no views. anyway this is my conf file.

DATABASE.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'ci';
$db['default']['password'] = 'ci';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I readed recently, some place dat it's no use to put a database name in the configuration when its based on oracle.

Any help will be welcomed.

ps:sorry about my english.

EDIT:
Now i know WHY, but not how to fix it, seems like this directly gets this query:

```
INSERT INTO "articulo" ("id", "titulo", "descripcion", "cuerpo") VALUES (1, 'titulo', 'descripcion', 'CUERPO')
```

it's a quote matter,  it shouldnt be putting quotes to the insert so it should be like this.

```
 INSERT INTO articulo (id, titulo, descripcion, cuerpo) VALUES (1, 'titulo', 'descripcion', 'CUERPO')
```

any tips?

RE-EDIT:

OK this is really insane,wasn't a quote problem, oracle seems to be case sensitive when u write querys from PHP(or at least from code igniter) I just put them in caps lock(as they are in oracle), and worked. so this is the final model's function:

```
function introducir_articulos(){
    $data = array(
            'ID'=>5,
            'TITULO'=>"titulo",
           'DESCRIPCION'=>"descripcion",
           'CUERPO'=>"CUERPO"

        );


    $this->db->insert("ARTICULO", $data);
```

}

couldnt answer my own question, so i answered it here.

Comment: first check you connection is working? try to select or any query for this

Comment: i tried to do a select * from table, and geting the row count,it returned 2(so its fine) , should i guess it connects correctly? im new to phpOO,and codeigniter, but not to php or MVC frameworks.

Comment: try with $this->db->query("your query");

Comment: it's finally answered by me, im new to stackoverflow, so i couldnt answer my own question till today. so i did in the question post(as stackoverflow recommends) did i did right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is really insane, oracle seems to be case sensitive when u write querys from PHP.(or at least from code igniter) just put them in caps lock, and worked.3 hours researching. so this is the final model's function:

```
function introducir_articulos(){
    $data = array(
            'ID'=>5,
            'TITULO'=>"titulo",
           'DESCRIPCION'=>"descripcion",
           'CUERPO'=>"CUERPO"

        );


    $this->db->insert("ARTICULO", $data);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration "DATABASE.php" you've should complete this statement

```
$db['default']['database'] = '';
```

Comment: I readed recently, some place dat it's no use to put a database name in the configuration when its based on oracle. dat's why i said dat, and believe me, i tried to put XE(its what answer me the select * from v$database;